# ThreadLocalRandom nextInt Without Range

Tags: java, random

Does [`ThreadLocalRandom`'s `nextInt()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt--) (i.e. the `nextInt()` method without any parameters) actually generate a pseudo-random integer without a range (i.e. between [`Integer.MIN_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE) and [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)) or is there some implicit range (e.g. only non-negative integers)?

The Javadoc doesn't explicitly state whether or not an implicit range is used but the [source code for `ThreadLocalRandom`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.java.html) seems to indicate that no range is used as `ThreadLocalRandom`'s `nextInt()` method is actually [`java.util.Random`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Random.java.html)'s `nextInt()` method, which calls [`java.util.Random.next(32)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#next-int-).

I'm fairly confident that any integer is pseudo-randomly generated using this method but I thought that I would double check with folks who are more familiar with this code and bit twiddling in general than I am. Thanks.

Comment: The Javadoc says everything about it: "All `2^32` possible int values are produced with (approximately) equal probability". What else do you need to know?

Comment: Totally missed that in Random's Javadoc. Knew I missing something obvious here. btw if you add that as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt--) says everything about it:

> "All 2^32 possible int values are produced with (approximately) equal
>   probability".

Is there something more to know?